# Anchor tags not working in DJANGO project do to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I have a project with many anchor tags and urls that connect many apps and pages. I also have a javascript file with some functions and DOM events to make somethings in my project.

If I add a the script element to my project base.html (that other pages are extending from) at the head of my base document without a `defer` attribute, it doesn't load the javascript file and it lets me use the anchor tags normal. But if I add the `defer` attribute to the script tag, it loads the javascript file but it doesn't let me use the anchor elements.

```html
<head>
    <!-- CODE THAT LETS RUN ANCHORS BUT DOESNT RUN JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="{% static '/js/script.js' %}"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}";
    </script>
  </head>
```

I have tried adding the javascript script tag before the `' and it loads the javascript file but it doenst

Comment: Update the question with the html file that's giving you problems. .

Comment: I thinks that update should help, theres a lot of code to upload everything

Comment: If everything in the head is working okay, just include the script tag, leave out the rest. But you haven't shown any anchor tag. Include two or three anchor tags of the body.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.